# Which one is correct? "Otherwise, as mentioned," or "Otherwise as mentioned,"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is correct? (for beginning of a sentence)

> Otherwise (or However), as mentioned, this model has higher accuracy comparing to that model.
>
> Otherwise (or However) as mentioned, this model has higher accuracy comparing to that model.

Comment: We need to see a complete sentence to give a useful answer.

Comment: @MickSharpe. Revised.

Comment: _as mentioned_ is a [parenthetical](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_06.htm) here, and should be set off with commas.

Comment: I find sentences beginning with **however** a little jarring. I would go for "As mentioned, however, this model...". Note that we normally say "compar**ed** to" rather than "compar**ing** to".

Answer (score -1):

"However, mentioned" is the correct term and (yay) is also the one that people use. This phrase points to something that you alluded to earlier i.e. "However, as I mentioned, this could just be a problem with X."

"As however mentioned" just doesn't make any sense, and isn't a natural thing to say, unless you are referring to a person named "however" that mentioned something.

Now into the real problem with this question: However, or Otherwise.

These are two very different words, and they don't mean the same things at all. Otherwise is referring to another option i.e. "Give it to me, otherwise I'll have to kill you", but However simply brings up another facet of the sentence without specifically adding to or detracting from the previous statement; "Give it to me and I'll spare her, however I'm going to have to kill *you* either way. Bwahahaa!"

If you needed to say "As otherwise mentioned" or "otherwise, as mentioned"  ( meaning you brought up you second point first, and are simply wanting to be confused i.e. "we could do B, or as otherwise mentioned,  we could do A") either option is acceptable. Please note however that you are better off just listing options in order, or using a less confusing word structure.